# Why does Debian sometimes ask me to insert the (installation?) cd when I install packages?

Tags: debian, apt

I've noticed sometimes when I do `apt-get` Debian asks me to insert [the installation cd I used] (6.0.6 amd64 dvd1). Sometimes it doesn't, although maybe it's because I've already mounted it earlier; I can't notice a definite pattern. Why is this? Does this happen with other flavors too? And I've searched for stuff like "virtualbox apt-get installation cd" with no luck (can't find a good query).

Comment: If you don't want for apt to search for the CD, comment it in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Ah course... seems so obvious in hindsight, but just learning linux and repositories and stuff. Thanks! If you answer, I'll mark it right after I double check with a package

Comment: Can you also remove the references to Virtualbox? Pretty sure it's just a Debian thing, having nothing to do with that...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A local CD can act as an APT repo, just as if it were a distant server.

If you don't want `apt-get` to search the CD, comment out the relevant line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` which looks something like this:

```
deb cdrom:[deb95amd64d1]/ stretch contrib main
```

To comment out the line, simply prefix it with a hash/pound symbol `#`.